# Changing URL in the web page

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, url, routes

How could i change the URL address while i'm moving from one tab to another tab within the same page? Where i want to change the code either in the routes.rb or in controller?

routes.rb:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :dashboard, only: [:index]
  resources :profile do
    collection do
      patch 'update_profile'
      patch 'change_password'

    end
  end

  devise_for :users, controllers: { omniauth_callbacks: 'users/omniauth_callbacks' }

  root 'dashboard#index'
end
```

My current url is `localhost:3000/profile`, now when i select update_profile tab i need the url to be `localhost:3000/profile/update_profile` without rendering the new page

controller code:

```
class ProfileController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_user, only: %i[index update_profile]

  def index

    @address = if @user.address
                 @user.address
               else
                 Address.new
               end
  end

  def update_profile
    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.update(user_params)
        format.html { redirect_to profile_index_path, notice: 'Profile was successfully updated.' }
      else
        format.html { render :index }
      end
    end
  end

  def change_password
   @user = current_user
    if @user.update_with_password(user_password_params)
      redirect_to root_path
    else
      render "index"
    end
 end

private

  def set_user
    @user = User.find(current_user.id)
  end

  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:name)
  end

  def address_params
    params.require(:user).permit(address: %i[area state country])
  end

  def user_password_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:password, :password_confirmation, :current_password)
  end
end
```

Comment: What happens (request-wise) when you click on a tab? Show the controller code.

Comment: I have added the controller code,can you please check it? @JagdeepSingh

Comment: What is the current behavior?

Comment: I'm getting the same url address while clicking the tab in the current page.i,e localhost:3000/profile for the both tabs.If i update the password changes the url got changed but i want the url changes while i'm clicking the tab