# Changing the url on selecting a tab

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, url, routes

I have various tab in my page which has url `profile` and when a tab is selected i want the url to change from `profile` to `profile/*selected_tab_name*`. The url is changed to what i need when the details is saved or after the form is submitted in the desired tab. I want the url to change once on pressing the tab. Can anyone help me with it!

Controller code

```
class ProfileController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_user, only: %i[index update_profile]

  def index

    @address = if @user.address
                 @user.address
               else
                 Address.new
               end
  end

  def update_profile
    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.update(user_params)
        format.html { redirect_to profile_index_path, notice: 'Profile was successfully updated.' }
      else
        format.html { render :index }
      end
    end
  end

  def change_password
   @user = current_user
    if @user.update_with_password(user_password_params)
      redirect_to root_path
    else
      render "index"
    end
 end

private

  def set_user
    @user = User.find(current_user.id)
  end

  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:name)
  end

  def address_params
    params.require(:user).permit(address: %i[area state country])
  end

  def user_password_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:password, :password_confirmation, :current_password)
  end
end
```

routes.rb

```
resources :profile do
   collection do
     patch 'update_profile'
     patch 'change_password'
   end
 end
```

View code

```
<li class="nav-item m-tabs__item">
          <a class="nav-link m-tabs__link active" data-toggle="tab" href="#m_user_profile_tab_1" role="tab">
            <i class="flaticon-share m--hide"></i>
            Update Profile
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item m-tabs__item">
          <a class="nav-link m-tabs__link" data-toggle="tab" href="#m_user_profile_tab_2" role="tab">
            Change Password
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item m-tabs__item">
          <a class="nav-link m-tabs__link" data-toggle="tab" href="#m_user_profile_tab_3" role="tab">
            Settings
          </a>
        </li>
```

terminal log

```
Started PATCH "/profile/change_password" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-05-15 10:20:55 +0530
Processing by ProfileController#change_password as HTML
 Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"KZDdXW/q89Iq2YBV0aobPi8hNXsn7sicGYgKs5/OOM0JF/1F8QOvHJdx9/S3st45VE1TrBWoJqmJIQage3QiyQ==", "user"=>{"current_password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"Save password"}
 User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 1 ORDER BY `users`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1
"============================="
  (0.2ms)  BEGIN
 SQL (0.3ms)  UPDATE `users` SET `encrypted_password` = '$2a$11$w14M.QgK7gBWtz.UyKamr.OdKn.O/gm9h/Vgb28uzaSZcH1SU7dSO', `updated_at` = '2018-05-15 04:50:55' WHERE `users`.`id` = 1
  (8.3ms)  COMMIT
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/
Completed 302 Found in 251ms (ActiveRecord: 9.1ms)
```

Comment: It is very much similar to a question asked yesterday https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50323880/changing-url-in-the-web-page

Answer (score 0):

Download Redmine for some excellent examples of Rails coding.

It does the "change URL on selecting a tab" trick like this:

```
function showTab(name, url) {
  $('#tab-content-' + name).parent().find('.tab-content').hide();
  $('#tab-content-' + name).parent().find('div.tabs a').removeClass('selected');
  $('#tab-content-' + name).show();
  $('#tab-' + name).addClass('selected');
  //replaces current URL with the "href" attribute of the current link
  //(only triggered if supported by browser)
  if ("replaceState" in window.history) {
    window.history.replaceState(null, document.title, url);
  }
  return false;
}
```

The tab itself sets its `onclick` to `"showTab('#{tab[:name]}', this.href); this.blur(); return false;"`. So apparently the `this.href` goes into `url`, then into `window.history.replaceState`.